# OpenAI API error 500: "The server had an error while processing your request", 503: "Service Unavailable" or 504: "Gateway Timeout"

Tags: python, openai-api, gpt-3

I created a Python script that loops through a list of text strings (each string is about 2000 characters in length) and summarizes each string. See the code for the response below (This prompt is within a for loop):

```
response = openai.Completion.create( model="text-davinci-003", max_tokens=2000, prompt = f"Summarize the following text: {text_list[i]}", temperature=0.5, frequency_penalty=1.5, presence_penalty=-1.5, n=1 )
```

It works for maybe 1 or 2 items in the text list but then I receive an error: `openai.error.APIError: The server had an error while processing your request. Sorry about that!`

This happens consistently even when I use different api keys, prompts, accounts. I have also tried exponential backoff with no success. Any idea what is happening?

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing. It never used to do this. I filed a couple of bug reports but they seem to have gone into a black hole.

Answer (score 1):

All `5xx` status codes mean **server error**. The problem is caused by OpenAI servers. Whether you get error `500`, `503` or `504`, it is not your fault.

List of HTTP status codes:

- `1xx` informational response
- `2xx` success
- `3xx` redirection
- `4xx` client errors
- `5xx` server errors

*Note: You can check OpenAI status [here](https://status.openai.com/).*