# Azure openAI API error while processing the request

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services, openai-api, azure-openai

I met some problems when using Azure OpenAI API. Here is the error information:

> The server had an error while processing your request. Sorry about
> that! You can retry your request, or contact us through an Azure
> support request at: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2213926 if
> the error persists. (Please include the request ID
> 154ea275-e40d-437a-87e4-31b76ef09568 in your message.)

Now I can't get Azure OpenAI service now.

I try to deploy the service again but it doesn't work. And I change the key, it doesn't work either.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OpenAI API error 500: "The server had an error while processing your request", 503: "Service Unavailable" or 504: "Gateway Timeout"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75196414/openai-api-error-500-the-server-had-an-error-while-processing-your-request-5)