# Error while using openai.Embedding.create in Pandas DataFrame apply function

Tags: request, response, chatbot, openai-api, openaiembeddings

I am encountering an issue while trying to apply the openai.Embedding.create function to a Pandas DataFrame using the apply method. The goal is to create a new column in the DataFrame called 'embeddings' by applying the function to the 'text' column.

Here's the relevant code snippet:

```
import pandas as pd
import openai



df['embeddings'] = df.text.apply(lambda x: openai.Embedding.create(input=x, engine='text-embedding-ada-002')['data'][0]['embedding'])
```

However, this code results in the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/adigweleo/web-crawl-q-and-a-example/web-qa.py", line 302, in <module>
    df['embeddings'] = df.text.apply(lambda x: openai.Embedding.create(input=x, engine='text-embedding-ada-002')['data'][0]['embedding'])
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
# ... (other parts of the error message)
openai.error.APIError: The server had an error while processing your request. Sorry about that! {
  "error": {
    "message": "The server had an error while processing your request. Sorry about that!",
    "type": "server_error",
    "param": null,
    "code": null
  }
}
```

I have waited for some time and retried the code multiple times, but the issue persists. Additionally, I have double-checked my API key, the inputs provided to the openai.Embedding.create function, and ensured that the necessary libraries are properly installed.

I expected the code to successfully create a new column 'embeddings' in the DataFrame, containing the embeddings for each 'text' entry. However, the encountered error suggests a server issue, and I'm unsure how to address it.

Any insights or suggestions on how to troubleshoot and resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Dealing with server-side errors in API responses can be frustrating, especially when the error messages do not provide specific details about the root cause. The error you're encountering with the openai.Embedding.create call suggests a problem on the server side, which is not directly within your control.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OpenAI API error 500: "The server had an error while processing your request", 503: "Service Unavailable" or 504: "Gateway Timeout"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75196414/openai-api-error-500-the-server-had-an-error-while-processing-your-request-5)